# Trying to Configure UIImageView Inside of UIStackView with Dynamic Images

Tags: uiimageview, autolayout

I have an `UITableViewCell` subclass used for displaying a social feed. I am having trouble figuring out how to configure my `UIImageViewCell`s to display images so that they retain their aspect ratio.

I have three images that I am trying to display in my `UITableViewCell`s to ensure that dynamic images are being displayed correctly, which they are not.

The following images are the test images:

[image: Image with landscape dimensions]

[image: Image with portrait dimensions]

[image: Image with square dimensions]

Here is the result of my attempt to display the images properly in my `UITableViewCell`s:

[image: Screenshot of table view]

I am using a `UIStackView` to contain body text, which is blurred out above each image in the cell, and the image below the body text. I have the body text's encompassing `UILabel` set to resize to fit the content, which works as expected.

The image's encompassing `UIImageView` is set up as follows:

- The `UIImageView` is set to have an equal width compared to the body text's `UILabel`.
- The `UIImageView`'s `contentMode` property is set to `.aspectFill`.

What I am expecting:

- The `UIImageView` should only grow to be as wide as the body text's `UILabel`.
- The `UIImageView` to retain the image's aspect ratio, allowing the `UIImageView`'s height to grow or shrink as necessary.

For reference, following is an image of my timeline from Tweetbot that displays what I am expecting. Notice that the images are all different sizes, retaining their correct aspect ratios:

[image: Screenshot of Tweetbot Timeline showing dynamic image sizes]

How can I configure Auto Layout with the missing constraints to allow my images to retain their aspect ratio when added to a `UIStackView`?

Comment: You have to do this from code. Get the size of the image after it has been downloaded and then modify the Ratio constraint on the image view.

Comment: We’re you able to solve this? I have a similar issue. I added a ratio constraint in code but that causes conflicting constraints, which I haven’t been able to solve. The conflicts must come from my stackview.